# how to disable active_admin's batch action?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems

I want to use gem best_in_place in active_admin for in-place editing. However, whenever I press Enter, it seems that active_admin captures that events and directs to XXXController's batch_action method. which is not found...

However, if after editing. I click a blank area..the best_in_place works and the database is updated...

So..how to fix it?

Answer (score 26):

A bit late but for everyone who comes here via Google:

```
    ActiveAdmin.register Product do
      config.batch_actions = false
      ...
    end
```

Comment: You can set this in the active_admin initializer rather than the resource definition. That way it applies to all